# Is it possible to have an S³ smooth manifold of constant curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

*Note: I am a mathematics enthusiast and may not be able to respond to any queries at the level they may be written at.*

I believe it is possible to create an (S¹)³ space that has constant curvature at all points, as we could make the dimensions form Clifford Toruses pair-wise.

However, S³ is quite different, especially if I further require it to have differentiation defined within it (I believe that is what "smooth" means?), and my knowledge doesn't extend that far.

Is it possible that an S³ space be a smooth manifold with constant curvature (i.e. identical to an Euclidean space).

Could anyone be kind enough to satisfy my curiosity?

Thank you.

Comment: There are many confusions in your question. 1) What is "an $S^3$ manifold?" 2) the usual metric on $S^3$ (induced by the embedding in $R^4$) is of constant curvature (sectional curvature = +1). 3) Constrant curvature $\neq$ Euclidean (which usually means curvature = 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sphere $\mathbb{S}^3:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4:|x|=1\}$ with the induced metric has constant positive curvature. Note however that $\mathbb{S}^3$ is not identical to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ has constant zero curvature, rather than positive curvature. Also, $\mathbb{S}^3$ is bounded, in the sense that it has a finite maximum distance between two points, but it is boundaryless in the sense that it is a manifold without boundary.

$\mathbb{S}^3$ is a smooth manifold. Remember that a set $M$ is a 3-dimensional manifold (without boundary) if for every $p \in M$, there is an open set $U_p \subset M$ and a homeomorphism (continuous invertible function) $\phi_p:U_p \to \phi_p(U_p)$, where $\phi_p(U_p)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. A (3-dimensional) manifold $M$ is a smooth manifold if there is a "smooth atlas" of homeomorphisms $\phi_p : p \in M$, i.e. for each $p,q \in M$ such that $U_p \cap U_q \ne \emptyset$, $\phi_q \cap \phi_p^{-1} : \phi_p(U_p \cap U_q) \to \phi_q (U_p \cap U_q)$ is a smooth function. Everyone has their own favourite textbook for this - I would recommend John M Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* as a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you. Especially for the book recommendation. Didier has also been enlightening. Now I wonder if $(\mathbb{S}^1)^3$ would do the trick (smooth, compact, "flat", basically indistinguishable from $\mathbb{R}^3$ unless you went in a straight line back to the start).

Comment: Yes, it would. It's isometric to the "quotient space" $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash (2\pi \mathbb{Z})^3$.

Comment: Thank you @1Rock!

Answer (score 0):

Not every smooth manifold with constant curvature is even homeomorphic to Euclidean space. Example: the "flat torus", consisting of all points of the form
$$
(\sin t, \cos t, \sin s, \cos s),
$$
where $0 \le s,t \le 2\pi$ has constant curvature zero, but is a torus (so in particular, it's compact, which Euclidean space is not).

The standard sphere in 4-space has constant curvature (although not zero-curvature; thanks, @Didier, for pointing out the impossibility of this!).

Comment: The sphere $S^3$ cannot have a flat metric, because every simply-connected complete flat manifold is homeomorphic to $R^n$ for some $n$

Comment: If I understand the meaning of homeomorphic, it would be necessary to have a bijective map between the two, which would have to be a map from a finite to an infinite space. I believe that is possible, but it would be quite a stretch for the kind of simplicity I'm looking for.
I do expect there to be a very simple bijective map onto a finite volume of an euclidean 3-space. Is it possible?

Comment: @Arkaevis what is the finite space and what is the infinite space here?

Comment: @Didier the finite space would be S³, I forgot to mention that. the infinite space would be R³

Comment: They are both infinite and in fact, there exists a bijection between them. However they are not homeomorphic because the sphere is compact and $R^3$ is not.

Comment: I thought S³ was unbounded but finite.
Then perhaps I misunderstood S³. Perhaps what I should have asked is if there is a flat closed, boundless, finite, 3-dimensional smooth manifold. Should I post another question? I may have made a XY question... sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124040/discussion-between-arkaevis-and-didier).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to isometrically glue Riemannian manifolds together like that, even when their boundaries are isometric. One needs to extend the isometry of boundaries $F:\partial M\to\partial N$ to an isometry collars, which requires among other things that $F^*II_{\partial N}=-II_{\partial M}$.

Comment: Thanks folks for the correction; I've edited (which makes some of your comments no longer relevant, but I think they're worth keeping around regardless).